# Use jQuery to trigger action based on data in MVC input box

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I am currently creating a MVC project that takes in data from a form/view generated from the model.

I want to be able to check user input in the form. If that input is less than 1, it would trigger another panel of information to open. The code below isn't quite functioning correctly. How exactly do I make this happen?

In my View:

```
      <div class="form-group">
           @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Buy2Yearsataddress, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
           <div class="col-md-10" id="coBuyerYearsAtAddress">
                   @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Buy2Yearsataddress, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                   @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Buy2Yearsataddress, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
      </div>
```

And here's what's in my script file:

```
    $("#coBuyerYearsAtAddress").focusout(function () {
         if ($("#coBuyerYearsAtAddress").val() <= 1) {
             $('#coBuyerPreviousResidence').show();
         }
         else {
             $('#coBuyerPreviousResidence').hide();
         }
});
```

Comment: Define "isn't quote functioning correctly".  What is the code doing?  What do you expect it to do?  Why?  When you step through the code in a debugger, where does it deviate from what you expect?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you are checking the value of coBuyerYearsAtAddress but you should be checking the value of "Buy2Yearsataddress" instead.

Comment: This fixed my issue completely. I knew it would be something super simple. Thank you so much! I appreciate it!

Answer (score 1):

Try the following

```
$('.form-control').change(function(){
    if ($(this).val() <= 1) {
        $('#coBuyerPreviousResidence').show();
    }
    else {
        $('#coBuyerPreviousResidence').hide();
    }
});
```

Comment: Second one almost worked. When input is entered, the panel pops up. However, it doesn't check the logic. In other words, I can enter a 0 or 300 and the panel pops up either way. Thoughts? Also, not quite sure exactly what you need as far as what the html is generated. I'd gladly give that info with clarification!

Comment: @cryan check now